# magento : search results redirects to live site

Tags: magento-1.9, url, search

when iam searching results in search box in my local site it redirects to live site,if results found.If not it is in local site only.why its happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Configuration:
System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Unsecure

Change all URLs to your local URL.

Do the same for "Secure".

Comment: all are local urls only

Comment: if you're using phpmyadmin you can search in your whole local database for your live url. This way, you don't have to search every table and column one by one

Answer (score 0):

After Change those Url Please clean your cache.